# Problem with menus and options being blank

Tags: interface, installation

[image: NOT SHOWING ANY MENU]

I am using Kali Linux latest version. I have graphics "Intel® Haswell Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2" and Core i3 laptop.

I installed Blender but its not showing any menu and any other option as you see in the picture.

What should I do?

Comment: sorry, but i am in very serious trouble. can u help me.

Comment: Try updating your graphics card drivers, reinstalling Blender also try the portable versions and deleting the preferences folder. Try previous versions as well - if they don't work it is more likely there is someething wrong with your computer and not Blender. Tthat might also be a bug. Questions about bugs are off topic on Blender Stack Exchange - not much anybody can do about them here - they should be reported to developers.